# How to write Hibernate query for collections Set

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have following Entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Date created;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<Language> languages = new HashSet<AlbumUser>()
}
```

and Language entity is

```
  @Entity
    public class Language{

    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") 
    private Employee employee;
}
```

my language table looks like following

[image]

I want to select all employee whose name starts with A and who knows java and C and to do so I am trying following

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Employee.class,"employee");
 criteria.add( Restrictions.ilike("name", "A%") );
 criteria.add(Restrictions.in("languages",languageSet));
 return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria)
```

where languageSet is

```
Set<Language> languageSet = new HashSet();
languageSet.add(new Language("Java"));
languageSet.add(new Language("C"));
```

I can see my attempt is completely wrong...I am new to hibernate can some one please help me with it..

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2100
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable using Hibernate ASSOCIATIONs with CRITERIA. While you look close to correct (while am not sure why you are using a DetachedCriteria, rather than a simple Criteria), you should refer this - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations - to figure out more on how should build such queries.

Comment: I already went through the link provided ... but since I am new to hibernate I am not able to follow the documentation ..so I am trying to learn by doing... Can you please let me know the query which i can use here

Comment: can you plz add the trace to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("languages.name",languageNames));
```

where languageNames is collection of language names.
If you have an error that "languages" cannot be solved, add new alias.